# What the OES means in "GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES"?

Tags: opengl-es, naming-conventions

I am reading the OpenGL documents from Apple. I noticed that a number of the GL names have the format `GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES`. What is the meaning of the `OES` part of these names?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OES is the "vendor"-code for the OpenGL ES working group. OES is used for any extensions that is developed by the working group. This is similar to the ARB-code for desktop-OpenGL.

Answer (score 5):

It means *OpenGL ES* : http://www.khronos.org/opengles/